# Set a global defined Variable in a step in azure pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

In short I want to overwrite a global defined variable, is this possible?

I know that I can output a variable from a step and [use it in another stage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#set-a-variable-for-future-stages). But I can not manage to overwrite an existing variable. I would like to use in a later stage the variable with a default set value but if it is set from a step to something else, I would like to use that

Is there a way to accomplish it?

Here is a pseudecode for it:

```
paramter
- createRelease = false

globalvar
- varA = 'test'


RunStage('A')
    RunJob('TestApplication')

    if(!createRelease) 
        RunJob('BuildForDev')

    if(createRelease)
        RunJob('BuildForUatRelease')
            RunStep('A')
                set varA: 'newValue'
                
RunStage('B')
    RunJob('Build')
        RunStep('UseVarA')
            - script: echo varA # should display 'newValue' not test
```

My Yaml so far:

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  
parameters:
  - name: releaseBuild
    displayName: 'Create a Release'
    type: boolean
    default: false
    
variables:
  - name: releaseBuild
    ${{if parameters.releaseBuild }}:
      value: 'true'
    ${{ elseif not(parameters.releaseBuild) }}:
      value: 'false'

  - name: dockerTagVersion
    value: 'latest'

stages:
  - stage: CI_Build
    displayName: Build and Test App
    jobs:
      - job: TestApplication
        displayName: Building and testing
        condition: always()
        steps:
          - task: Bash@3
            displayName: Maven Test Application
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                echo 'mvn test'

      - job: BuildForDev
        displayName: Build Application for Develop
        dependsOn: TestApplication
        condition: |
          and(
            succeeded('TestApplication'),
            eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main'),
            eq(variables.releaseBuild, 'false')
          )
        steps:
          - task: Bash@3
            displayName: Maven test Application
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                echo mvn test
      - job: BuildForUatRelease
        displayName: Release Application
        dependsOn: TestApplication
        condition: |
          and(
            succeeded('TestApplication'),
            eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main'),
            eq(variables.releaseBuild, 'true')
          )
        steps:
          - task: Bash@3
            displayName: Set Git Credentials
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                echo 'mvn release prepare'

          - bash: echo $(dockerTagVersion)
          - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=dockerTagVersion;isoutput=true]crushed tomatoes"
            name: dockerTagVersion
          - bash: echo $(dockerTagVersion)
  - stage: CD_DEV_Deployment
    displayName: CD Deploy to DEV
    condition: |
      and
      (
        succeeded(),
        true
      )
    jobs:
      - job: BuildForUatRelease
        displayName: Release Application
        variables:
          ciBuildDockerTag:  $[ stageDependencies.CI_Build.A.outputs['ProduceVar.MyVar'] ]
        steps:
           - bash: echo $(dockerTagVersion)
```

Answer (score 0):

When specifying variables through the `##vso[task.setvariable]` syntax, you must pay attention to the `isoutput=true` attribute.

when `isoutput` is `true` means you need to access the variable through `[step_name].[variable_name]`

when `isoutput` is `false`  means you need to access the variable through `[variable_name]` only.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to modify your below code

```
ciBuildDockerTag:  $[ stageDependencies.CI_Build.A.outputs['ProduceVar.MyVar'] ]
```

So the syntax is

```
stageDependencies.STAGE.JOB.outputs['TASK.VARIABLE']
```

variable `dockerTagVersion` is assigned at job `BuildForUatRelease` and in step `dockerTagVersion`, so fix above as

```
ciBuildDockerTag:  $[ stageDependencies.CI_Build.BuildForUatRelease.outputs['dockerTagVersion.dockerTagVersion'] ]
```

*Note: also set `isOutput=true` and 'O' is caps*